Add sign to PDF using old iText-2.1.7
I'm working on a legacy project that uses the old iText-2.1.7 library. I'm just starting to figure it out and I won't be upgrading to a more modern version yet, so I need help with this version specifically.
I need add signature to pdf, here is my code:
def postProcessPdf(pdf: Array[Byte], os: OutputStream): Unit = {
 val reader = new PdfReader(pdf)
 Security.addProvider(new KalkanProvider)
 val stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\u0000')
 val appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance
 val signDate = Calendar.getInstance
 val pdfSignature = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED)
 pdfSignature.setDate(new PdfDate(signDate))
 pdfSignature.setCert(CryptUtils.cert.getEncoded)
 appearance.setCryptoDictionary(pdfSignature)
 appearance.setCrypto(null, CryptUtils.chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED)
 appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED)
 val estimatedSize = 8192
 val exc = new HashMap[PdfName, Int]()
 exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, estimatedSize * 2 + 2)
 appearance.preClose(exc)
 val data = appearance.getRangeStream()
 val sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, CryptUtils.chain, null, "SHA256", null, false)
 val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256","KALKAN")
 val dataBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(data)
 digest.update(dataBytes)
 val appeareanceHash = digest.digest()
 val hashToSign = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(appeareanceHash, appearance.getSignDate(), null)
 val signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA","KALKAN")
 signature.initSign(CryptUtils.privateKey)
 signature.update(hashToSign)
 val signedHash = signature.sign()
 sgn.setExternalDigest(signedHash,null,"RSA")
 val encodedPKCS7 = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(signedHash, appearance.getSignDate())
 val paddedSig = new Array[Byte](estimatedSize)
 System.arraycopy(encodedPKCS7, 0, paddedSig, 0, encodedPKCS7.length)
 val dic = new PdfDictionary()
 dic.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).setHexWriting(true))
 appearance.close(dic)
}

Result in Adobe Acrobat Reader:
image
Error: Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed. What is mean and what i supposed to do? Thank you in advance.
PDF-file: link

Please share an example PDF signed by your code.

@mkl i added link to question

I also forgot to mention that for testing I use expired digital signature

See my answer, based on the example file I could determine one bug. If after fixing that bug there still are "document has been altered or corrupted" issues, please provide a new example PDF signed with the fixed code.

You have to use the same parameter values for the matching parameters of your sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes and sgn.getEncodedPKCS7 calls.
In your code you have:
val hashToSign = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(appeareanceHash, appearance.getSignDate(), null)
...
sgn.setExternalDigest(signedHash,null,"RSA")
val encodedPKCS7 = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(signedHash, appearance.getSignDate())

but it should be
val hashToSign = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(appeareanceHash, appearance.getSignDate(), null)
...
sgn.setExternalDigest(signedHash,null,"RSA")
val encodedPKCS7 = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(appeareanceHash, appearance.getSignDate())


It works. Thank you!
